# Spring Reactor multiple subscription

Tags: rx-java2, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to split my mono to other separated mono which will be processed the same data input data on different threads.

```
public Mono<String> process() { 
        Mono<String> someString = ... // fetching data from API 



        someString
                .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)))
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .subscribe(this::saveLowercase);

        someString
                .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)))
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .subscribe(this::saveUpperCase);

        return someString;
}
```

I saw in logs that I fetched data 3 times because each subscription call fetching data from API. I wanted to use the .cache() method but I wonder that some new better ways to call only once API and processed multiply this data? I can exchange the Reactor into RxJava if Reactor can't do this.

Comment: i think you need to take a step back and read up on the basics of reactive programming. The subscriber is the one that initiated the call, a web client, a gui, or a schedulare etc. etc. You almost never subscribe in your own application like you have done here.

Answer (score 4):

In the example you gave, you created a cold `Mono`. So the `HTTP` call would take place for each `subscriber`, as you said. If you want the `HTTP` call to take place only once, create hot observable. You'll have to use `.cache()` so that any future subscribers get the response.

This is the proper way to do this. Why are you looking for "something better"?

Example from the official documentation:

```
DirectProcessor<String> hotSource = DirectProcessor.create();

Flux<String> hotFlux = hotSource.map(String::toUpperCase).cache();


hotFlux.subscribe(d -> System.out.println("Subscriber 1 to Hot Source: "+d));

hotSource.onNext("blue");
hotSource.onNext("green");

hotFlux.subscribe(d -> System.out.println("Subscriber 2 to Hot Source: "+d));

hotSource.onNext("orange");
hotSource.onNext("purple");
hotSource.onComplete();
```

Both the subscribers will get all the colors now.

Comment: The finally solution is publish method which can be used as sub stream event and this operation doesn’t call new subscription to upstream.